# How to change position of input form and label if there is at least one symbol in form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am using this stuff: https://github.com/maman/JVFloat.js/tree/master. When you start typing, placeholder text appears as small label over input form. How to change position of input form and label if there is at least one symbol in form? I want to make it a bit lower.How can i make this kind of animation?

Comment: Can you post whatever code you've got so far and highlight the specific areas with which you need help?

Comment: for example, to add class if there is at least one symbol in form they are using this code:       function setState () {
        // change span.placeHolder to span.placeHolder.active
        var currentValue = $el.val();

        if (currentValue == null) {
          currentValue = '';
        }
        else if ($el.is('select')) {
          var placeholderValue = getPlaceholderText($el);

          if (placeholderValue == currentValue) {
            currentValue = '';
          }
        }

        placeholder.toggleClass('active', currentValue !== '');
      }